# How do I prove that $R^n\setminus R^k$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-k-1}\times R^{k+1}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $k,n$ be positive integers such that $k<n$.

How do I prove that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \mathbb{R}^k$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-k-1}\times \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$?

I tried to put specific integers in $k,n$ to visualize the problem. However, I even have a trouble with this.

The case $k=2,n=3$ is clear.

Consider the case $k=1,n=3$.

Using deformation retractions, it's clear that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\pi_1(S^1)$. Hence, this approach does not help prove the statement..

How do I prove it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to show that $\Bbb R^n\setminus\Bbb R^0 \cong S^{n-1}\times\Bbb R$ for all $n>0$. An isomorphism is given by the map $x\mapsto(x/||x||,||x||)$.

So assume by induction that $\Bbb R^n\setminus\Bbb R^k \cong S^{n-k-1}\times\Bbb R^{k+1}$ for some $k$ and for all $n>k$. Then if we take $\Bbb R^{n+1}\setminus\Bbb R^{k+1}$, for some $n>k$, this is homeomorphic to $(\Bbb R^n\setminus\Bbb R^k)\times\Bbb R$, which by induction is $S^{n-k-1}\times\Bbb R^{k+1}\times\Bbb R\cong S^{(n+1)-(k+1)-1}\times\Bbb R^{(k+1)+1}$

Comment: So, should I use algebraic topology only when it is asked to prove "$X,Y$ are **not** homeomorphic" in general? (at least in undegraduate level)

Comment: @Rubertos: That's actually the goal of algebraic topology. To use algebraic invariants of spaces in order to show that two spaces are not homotopy equivalent (which implies they are not homeomorphic). These tools are usually not capable of showing that spaces **are** homeomorphic (although for certain nice spaces, they  could show that they are homotopy equivalent).