# Prove that $R^{n}\setminus R^{k} \simeq S^{n} \setminus S^{k} \simeq S^{n-k-1} $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$\simeq$ is homotopy equivalence space

**homotopy equivalence:**

Two topological spaces X and Y are homotopy equivalent if there exist continuous maps $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$, such that the composition f degreesg is homotopic to the identity $id_Y$ on Y, and such that g degrees f is homotopic to $id_X$. Each of the maps f and g is called a homotopy equivalence, and g is said to be a homotopy inverse to f (and vice versa).

**homotopy:**

In topology, two continuous functions from one topological space to another are called homotopic if one can be "continuously deformed" into the other, such a deformation being called a homotopy between the two functions.

$\setminus$ is set minus (dont mistake it with quotient space)

**hint:** there is similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365457/how-do-i-prove-that-rn-setminus-rk-is-homeomorphic-to-sn-k-1-times-rk) but its not usable for this question because first of all it proves $R^{n}\setminus R^{k} \simeq S^{n-k-1} \times R^{k+1}$

The answer tried to solved it by using induction on k,
 and the right term  $R^{k+1}$ play important roll which can not be omitted from that proof. and if I wanted to prove it by induction on k

k=0

$R^{n} \setminus R^{0} \simeq S^{n-1}$

I can prove the initial case very similar by giving the map: $x \rightarrow (x/ ||x||)$

however I have no idea for the induction step. and for the middle part of the proof which says: $\simeq S^{n} \setminus S^{k}$

Comment: I don't know what your intention in the title was exactly, but do not do line breaks in titles.

Comment: First of, the actual question should be incorporated in the question body. Second, please don't use line breaks in the title (see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles/9730#9730)). Third, why is the approach not usable; please add you attempted tries with an [edit].

Comment: Your question confuses two related but distinct mathematical concepts.

First, two continuous *functions* $f,g : X \to Y$ are **homotopic** if there exists a continuous function $H : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$.

Second, two *topological spaces* $X$ and $Y$ are **homotopy equivalent** if there exists a continuous function $h : X \to Y$ and a continuous function $k : Y \to X$ such that the two functions $k \circ h : X \to X$ and $\text{Id}_X : X \to X$ are homotopic, and the two functions $h \circ k : Y \to Y$ and $\text{Id}_Y : Y \to Y$ are homotopic.

Comment: Keep in mind, a statement asserting that two spaces are "homotopic" has no meaning, and is an abuse of mathematical grammar and terminology.

Comment: @ Lee Mosher Thank you very much I edited it accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is imprecise because you do not specify how $\mathbb R^k$ is regarded a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ (similarly for $S^k$ and $S^n$). But certainly you identity 
$\mathbb R^k$ with $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n \mid x_{k+1} = \ldots = x_n = 0 \}$ and $S^k$ with $\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) \in S^n \mid x_{k+2} = \ldots = x_{n+1} = 0 \}$.

Let $p = (1,0,\ldots,0) \in S^n$. Stereographic projection gives us a homeomorphism
$$h : S^n \setminus \{p \} \to \mathbb R^n, h(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1}) =\left(\frac{x_2}{1-x_1},\ldots,\frac{x_{n+1}}{1-x_1}\right) .$$
We have $h(S^k \setminus \{p \}) = \mathbb R^k$, thus $h((S^n \setminus \{p \}) \setminus (S^k \setminus \{p \})) = \mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k$. But clearly $(S^n \setminus \{p \}) \setminus (S^k \setminus \{p \}) = S^n \setminus S^k$ which proves that $\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k$ and $S^n \setminus S^k$ are homeomorphic.

As you stated in your question, $\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k$  and $S^{n-k-1} \times \mathbb R^{k+1}$ are homotopy equivalent which implies $\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k \simeq S^{n-k-1}$ because $\mathbb R^{k+1}$ is contractible.

Comment: thank for your answer for the one part.I didnt stated that I just wanted to explain the proof and the relation of the given similar question I am not sure you can deduct by using the fact that $R^ {k+1}$ is contractible.

Comment: @Niloofar_jz You have $\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^0 \simeq S^{n-1}$. The inductive step is $\mathbb R^{n+1} \setminus \mathbb R^{k+1} \approx (\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k) \times \mathbb  R \simeq \mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k \simeq S^{n-k-1}$.

Comment: yes this is the very proof. thank you. Could you explain why you say  $(R^n\setminus R^k) \times R \simeq R^n\setminus R^k$

Comment: @name You have $\mathbb R \simeq *$ = one-point space, thus $X \times \mathbb R \simeq X \times * \approx X$ for any $X$.